# Get Like Count and Comment details from facebook in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access the `like` count and `comments` of specific shares from `Facebook`.

Suggest me some method to retrieve the `like count` and `comments of that.

Now i am getting post id for specific share....

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"http://samples.ogp.me/XXXXXXXXXX", @"object",
                           nil
                       ];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {

                      }];
```

But i am not getting any response for it

Please help me...

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read the Facebook SDK documentation? Post some code that show that you tried to solve this issue your self. Because your question as it is now looks like a code request, which is frowned up and my get your question downvoted or closed.

Comment: You shouldn't post your App Access Token publically!

Comment: Now i am able to share the post. My problem is getting back the response. I am unable to get the like and comments back to my app. i can get the like count by this link graph.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/… but dont no how to use this in my app @rckoenes

Comment: is there any method to retrieve the like count and comments @Tobi

Comment: What do you mean with "specific shares from Facebook" ? Posts? And, you already wrote that you can get them, so where's the problem?

Comment: question edited @Tobi

Comment: Doesn't help at all... You're (wrong) showing OpenGraph code, what kind of Graph API obejcts do you want to query for comments and likes?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this solution to get likes count:

```
NSString *likesRequestURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+total_count,+url+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+=\"%@\"&access_token=%@", URL, FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken ? FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken : self.fbToken] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:likesRequestURL]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0f];

__block NSString *result = [NSString string];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (error == nil) {
                               NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                               SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
                               result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString] objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"total_count"]];
                               [jsonString release];
                           } else {
                               NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
                           }
                       }];
```

It works.

P.S.: I used `SBJSONParser`, but if you want to use some other, just change corresponding code, it's easy.

Comment: which URL i have to give

Comment: URL is an array of URLs for which you want to get likes count separated by comma, or single URL.